# Youtube Direct Authentication to access JSON-RPC API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a set up a youtube direct app on the google appengine and would like to access the list of videos in an assignment. https://app_id.appspot.com/jsonrpc is the address I need to post my queries to. In order to do so I need to be authenticated as an admin. How do I authenticate myself using python (possibly gdata API)?